# Python generating prime numbers using Set Comprehension

Tags: python, set-comprehension

I am working on an assignment in beginning Python calling for a list of primes less then 100 using set comprehension. I can generate non primes using

```
nonPrime = { x for x in range(2, 100) for y in range(2, x) if x % y == 0 }
```

This effectively returns all non prime numbers but I can not find a way other than to Excursive Or this set with a set of all numbers from 2 to 100 to get a set of prime numbers. Is there a way that I can get the opposite of this set within the same set comprehension?

Comment: What are `o` and `Y` set to? Or was that meant to be `x % y == 0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the most efficient algorithm, but to implement it:

```
prime = {x for x in range(2, 100) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x))}
```

Or, equivalently:

```
prime = {x for x in range(2, 100) if not any(x % y == 0 for y in range(2, x))}
```

For one simple refinement, you can stop checking for possible factors once you've passed the square root of `x`:

```
prime = {x for x in range(2, 100) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, int(math.floor(math.sqrt(x))) + 1))}
```

Comment: gracefully its good to use  [ ...] than {...} as we are creating list finally.List Comprehension.